# プロセスを生成できません

Tags: c++

C++Builder　community　win10　コンパイルすると「プロセスを生成できません。」のエラーが出ます。対処法方法ご教示ください。

Comment: イベントログに原因が記録されていたりしませんか？

Comment: 「アクセスが拒否されました」とあります。

Comment: 追記　これはSDIフォームでだけ起こり,MDIでは正常に動くことがわかりました。